# Parse JSON from webpage

Tags: php, android, json

I made a php script which connects to my database and parse in JSON format some news. My problem is that the content of the news are in HTML format - with  `<br> , <img>` and so on(so when I open the script - ex: `http://localhost/android_connect/get_news.php` the browser interprets the HTML tags as it was designed to) . 
Is there anyway to parse from JSON the

`view-source:http://localhost/android_connect/get_news.php`

webpage?

Comment: If it literally includes the html tags in your json string (without any encoding) then its not a proper json response. Please include some sample json string in your question for a clear picture of problem.

Comment: json is a format that lets you structure the data, if you want the data in your html page to be structured in to a json format you first need to construct that data with in php and call `json_encode`

Comment: This sounds like you want to call strip_tags() on your DB result before calling json_encode() in your script.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can read the source of the HTML page with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
$json_news = file_get_contents ("http://localhost/android_connect/get_news.php");
echo $json_news;
```

Comment: Wait, do you mean you want to get the contents *with* the HTML tags intact, or *without* the HTML tags? If it's the latter, then you can call [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). I thought you wanted the former because you said you want to parse the JSON from `view-source:http://localhost/android_connect/get_news.php`